# Find the lowest and rightmost pixel to find angle of image

Tags: matlab

I am trying to apply an imrotate to an image however the angle of the image is unknown and changes with each image.

If i have converted the image to binary would it be possible to find the lowest y position '1' and the leftmost'1' and use the gradient/angle between them as the angle for my image rotate?

for example:
[binary positions diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le2J4.png)

Using the angle between these two positions and aligning it with the x axis?

Current Progress - converted to binary and made the edges more distinguishable:

```
% convert to binary
greyImage = rgb2gray(C); % greyscale
cannyImage = edge(greyImage, 'canny'); % canny edge detection

% fill the gaps in the shape
se = strel('disk',2);
bw = imclose(cannyImage, se);

filled = imfill(bw, 'holes');

imshow(filled);

[~,lowerMostCol] = max(cumsum(sum(filled,2)));
[~,leftMostRow] = max(sum(filled,1)==1);
```

Comment: share what you had done so far.

Comment: @Sachith updated with where I am currently at.

Comment: that is good.this will help other people to understand what you had done so far.also you will get the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

With `a` as the binary image, you could do something like this -

```
[~,lowermost] = max(cumsum(sum(a,2)));
lowermostpt = [lowermost,find(a(lowermost,:),1,'first')]

[~,rightmost] = max(cumsum(sum(a,1)));
rightmostpt = [find(a(:,rightmost),1,'first'),rightmost]

[~,topmost] = max(sum(a,2)==1);
topmostpt = [topmost,find(a(topmost,:),1,'first')]

[~,leftmost] = max(sum(a,1)==1);
leftmostpt = [find(a(:,leftmost),1,'first'),leftmost]
```

For performance efficiency, it might be a good idea to store the summations once and re-use later on.

Sample run -

```
a =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
lowermostpt =
    12    10
rightmostpt =
     8    14
topmostpt =
     4    10
leftmostpt =
     8     6
```

---

**Approach #2** Using [`bwboundaries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) from Image-processing toolbox -

```
idx = cell2mat(bwboundaries(a))

[~,p1] = min(idx(:,1))
topmostpt = idx(p1,:)
[~,p2] = max(idx(:,1))
lowermostpt = idx(p2,:)

[~,p3] = min(idx(:,2))
leftmostpt = idx(p3,:)
[~,p4] = max(idx(:,2))
rightmostpt = idx(p4,:)
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have a column number for left-most and row number for lower-most, how can I specify that specific position, and find the gradient between the two positions?

Note: for the images to be tested there will always be a straight edge between leftmost-lowermost. Hence I chose left over rightmost.

Comment: @AlexS Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. You were looking to get both X and Y. So, please check out the just added edits.

Comment: thank you for that update, I have to work now but I will continue having a crack at this in 4 hours. Cheers, Alex.

Comment: Where's the `fun` in this?

Comment: @Adriaan Get a box to fit that baby into : `bsxfun(@times,sum(a,1),sum(a,2))>0` ;)

Comment: @AlexS I am not sure really. Time those on your use case I guess.

Comment: @Divakar yes by 0.05s. Can I mark this complete somehow? I have managed to rotate and do the cropping I needed to, so all done. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AlexS Not sure what you mean by complete, but yeah nothing else from me on this :)

Comment: Complete/question solved, gave yours the green tick.

Comment: @AlexS Yup, that's it! Thanks.